# Multiple Range.Find() in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2007

I have met this interesting problem today. I have a loop inside another loop and both use `Find` for different purposes. What happens is that using `Find` in the inside loop screws up the `Find` on the outer loop. I'm guessing [excel](/questions/tagged/excel) keeps memory of only one search instance. Is there some way to work around this or is this a design matter ?

Here's some shortened version of my code.

```
Sub Main()
    'Some boring stuff

    Set lst_rapports = Worksheets("mappingTRANSIT").range("lst_rapports")
    Set first_result = lst_rapports.Find(rap_choisi)
    Set active_result = first_result

    Sheets("req01").Unprotect "shoobidoowap"
    If Not first_result Is Nothing Then
        ' ...            
        Do
            Sheets("req01").Select            
            ' ...
            For i = 0 To 4
                Set rubrique_cell = range("E:E").Find(rub(i))
                If Not rubrique_cell Is Nothing Then
                    ' ...
                End If
            Next i                
            ' Yet more boring stuff...

            Set active_result = lst_rapports.FindNext(active_result)
        Loop Until active_result.Address = first_result.Address
    Else
        MsgBox "Impossible de trouver """ & rap_choisi & """ !"
    End If
    Sheets("req01").Protect "shoobidoowap"
End Sub
```

Notice the second use of `.Find` in the for loop.

Is there some way I can preserve the first search in some kind of temporary variable and restore it back after that ?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you run `FindNext`[(MSDN for FindNext)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196143.aspx), it automatically uses the same `what` as the last call on `Find`, even if used for a different range.

To correct for this, instead of using

`Set active_result = lst_rapports.FindNext(active_result)`

use

`Set active_result = lst_rapports.Find(rap_choisi,active_result)`